# How to use Azure Batch in an event based design and terminate/cleanup finished jobs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-batch

Using Azure Batch, my project adds jobs to a pool using an event based design with functions and queues. When the job is finished, it is still "active", even though all tasks are completed.

A (single using an app service plan) function is triggered on a timer which reads an X amount of messages from the queue. The function:

- Creates a pool (if it does not exist)
- Creates a job
- Adds the tasks to that job

That works good. However, once the tasks have finished, the job status remains active, even though all tasks have finished. I want the jobs to terminate/cleanup/set the status to "completed".

And I want my functions to be short-lived and do not want any statefullness. So I am not using `foreach (CloudTask task in job.CompletedTasks())` to await the status of the tasks.

Another approach is to use task dependencies, which require `batchClient.Utilities.CreateTaskStateMonitor()` and thus a statefull approach.

What is the best way to use Azure Batch in an event based design? And specifically, how to terminate/cleanup the jobs once the tasks are finished?

Comment: Don't add a solution to your question. Instead write it as an answer because that is what they are for :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. Done.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the job "auto complete" once all tasks complete under the job. There is a property called [OnAllTasksComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.cloudjob.onalltaskscomplete?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_CloudJob_OnAllTasksComplete) on the CloudJob object.

You will want to initially set this [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.common.onalltaskscomplete?view=azure-dotnet) to `NoAction` (the default), while you are adding tasks to the job. After you have added all the tasks to the job, you can update that value to `TerminateJob` and then call `Commit()/CommitAsync()`. Note that if you retain the CloudJob that you initially submitted, you will need to `Refresh()/RefreshAsync()` first before modifying the properties and committing. Alternativley you can `GetJob()/GetJobAsync()`, modify, then commit.

For event-based designs, you can take a look at enabling [Batch service analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-diagnostics) and see if that is appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Wonderful, thank yo so much! This way the code is as stateless as it can be, without a watcher/waiting process. I don't have to watch for events like when a pool is created, only the processing side using Azure Batch..

Answer (score 0):

Final solution with code after fpark's answer:

```cs
public class Orchestrator()
{
    public Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        // Create the Batch pool, which contains the compute nodes 
        // that execute the tasks.
        var pool = await _batchManager.CreatePoolIfNotExistsAsync();

        // Create the job that runs the tasks.
        var job = await _batchManager.CreateJobIfNotExistsAsync(_domain, pool.Id);

        // Obtain the bound job from the Batch service
        await job.RefreshAsync();

        // Create a collection of tasks and add them to the Batch job. 
        var tasks = await _fileProcessingTasksFactory.CreateAsync(job.Id);

        // Add the tasks to the job; the tasks are automatically scheduled
        // for execution on the nodes by the Batch service.
        await job.AddTaskAsync(tasks);

        job.OnAllTasksComplete = OnAllTasksComplete.TerminateJob;

        await job.CommitAsync();
    }
}

public class BatchManager()

    public async Task<CloudPool> CreatePoolIfNotExistsAsync()
    {
        // Code to create and return a pool.
    }

    public async Task<CloudJob> CreateJobIfNotExistsAsync(string domain, string poolId)
    {
        // Job id cannot contain : so replace them.
        var jobId = $"{domain}-{DateTime.UtcNow:s}".Replace(":", "-");
        var job = _parameters.BatchClient.JobOperations.CreateJob();

        job.Id = jobId;
        job.PoolInformation = new PoolInformation { PoolId = poolId };

        await job.CommitAsync();

        return job;
    }
}
```

If you try to create a job with `OnAllTasksComplete.TerminateJob` directly, you will receive the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
2018-03-27 07:57:40.738 +02:00 [Error] "636577269909538505" - Failure while scheduling Azure Batch tasks.
System.InvalidOperationException: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PropertyAccessor`1.ThrowIfReadOnly(Boolean overrideReadOnly)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PropertyAccessor`1.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<SetValue>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PropertyAccessController.WriteProperty(Action propertyWriteAction, BindingAccess allowedAccess, String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.PropertyAccessor`1.SetValue(T value, Boolean overrideReadOnly, Boolean overrideAccessControl)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.CloudJob.set_OnAllTasksComplete(Nullable`1 value)
   at BatchManager.CreateJobIfNotExist(String domain, String poolId) in C:\ProjectsGitHub\ProjectName\BatchManager.cs:line 107
   at FileProcessingOrchestrator.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\ProjectsGitHub\ProjectName\FileProcessingOrchestrator.cs:line 48
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nnip.Qrs.EdgarDataProcessing.Parallelization.FunctionApp.ScheduleAzureBatchTasks.<Run>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\ProjectsGitHub\ProjectName\FunctionApp\ScheduleAzureBatchTasks.cs:line 93

Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: ScheduleAzureBatchTasks. Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
Exception while executing function: ScheduleAzureBatchTasks
Exception while executing function: ScheduleAzureBatchTasks. Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
Function completed (Failure, Id=6173b9d2-5058-4a6d-9406-1cf00340774e, Duration=71076ms)

Executed 'ScheduleAzureBatchTasks' (Failed, Id=6173b9d2-5058-4a6d-9406-1cf00340774e)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ScheduleAzureBatchTasks. Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
  Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '6173b9d2-5058-4a6d-9406-1cf00340774e'
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ScheduleAzureBatchTasks. Microsoft.Azure.Batch: This object is in an invalid state.  Write access is not allowed.
```

So set the `job.OnAllTasksComplete` when all tasks have been added.

It takes around two minutes (in my case) for the job to set it's status to `Completed` after all the tasks are completed.