# Add Tasks to a running Azure batch job and manually control termination

Tags: azure, azure-batch

We have an Azure-batch job that uses some quite large files which we are uploading to Azure Blob storage asynchronously so that we don't have to wait for all files to upload before starting our batch job made up of a collection of Tasks that will process each file and generate output. All good so far - this is working fine.

I'd like to be able to create an Azure Task and Add it to an existing, running Azure Job increasing the length of the Task list but I cant find how to do this. It seems that Azure expects you to define ALL jobs for a Task before the Job starts and then it runs until all tasks are complete and terminates the job (which makes sense in some scenarios - but not mine).

I would like to suppress this Job completion behavior and be able to queue up additional Azure Tasks for the same job. I could then monitor the Azure Job status (via the Tasks) and determine myself if the Job is complete.

Our issue is that uploads of multi-MB files takes time and we want Task processing to start as soon as the first file is available. If we have to wait until all files are available, then our processing start is delayed which is not what we need.

We 'could'create a job per task and manage it in our application but that is a little 'messy' and I would like to use the encapsulating Azure Job entity and supporting functionality if I possibly can.

Has anyone done this and can offer some guidance? Many thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new tasks to an existing Azure Batch job in the `active` state. There is no `running` state for an Azure Batch job. You can find a list of Azure Batch job states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/job/get#jobstate).

Azure Batch Jobs, by default, do not automatically complete by terminating upon all tasks completing. You can view this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488207/how-to-use-azure-batch-in-an-event-based-design-and-terminate-cleanup-finished-j) regarding this subject.

Comment: Thank you - that clarifies for me and means we can implement this solution 'cleanly' in line with Azure batch architecture. Many thanks.